# looping through column data to fit curve in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, multiple-columns, curve-fitting

I have a spreadsheet `ANA2009_1ag.xlsx` with column 1= wavelength lambda and col2=specta1, col3=spectra2, col4=spectra3 etc

I want to fit a curve to each of the spectra using the equation:

`ag(lambda) = ag(lambda_o)*exp(-S(lambda-lambda_o)`

So I can get the slope `S`.

I have the code and I am able to run it if I have a text file with 2 columns:
column 1= wavelength lambda and col2=specta1
But as i said above I have several spectra so i would like to make a loop so that the routine i got for fitting the curve and getting the slope loops from one column to the next.  ut as a novice in matlab loops are my biggest problem. 
My code is as follows.

```
%//%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
[num,txt,raw]=xlsread('ANA2009_1ag.xlsx');

%// Get the size of data to be plotted 
[r,c]=size(num);

%//%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %// using txt vector to make appropriate legend that matches the data plot
   Sepctra=cellstr(txt); %//C = cellstr converts array to a cell array.
   %//FIND OUT HOW YOU CAN SAY TO END OF COLUMN 
for i=2:7
   Sepctra(i)=txt(i);
end   

%//%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%//takeout range of interest
I=find(num(:,1)<650 & num(:,1)>400);

wl=num(I,1);
a_g=num(I,2);


%//setting options for fmisearch
opts = optimset('fminsearch');      
opts = optimset(opts,'MaxIter',4000); 
opts = optimset(opts,'MaxFunEvals',2000);   %// usually 100*number of params
opts = optimset(opts,'TolFun',1e-9);
%//opts = optimset('LevenbergMarquardt','on');

%//guess for paramters (amplitude at 532 and slope)
x0=[0.1, 0.03];

%//minimization routine
x1 = fminsearch(@least_squares,x0,opts,a_g,wl)

%//plot data and fit
plot(wl, a_g, '.k', wl, x1(1)*exp(-x1(2)*(wl-412)),'b')
```

DATA IS FROM 300 NM (LAMBDA) TO 685 NM (lambda) BUT I CHOSE TO FIT THE CURVE FROM 650-400NM

```
Wavelength  AN10070A-4m AN10066A-10m 
300         1.561434    1.434769
300.5       1.549919    1.42786 
301         1.531495    1.414042
301.5       1.506162    1.400224 
302         1.483132    1.386406
302.5       1.467011    1.372588 
303         1.45089     1.356467
303.5       1.443981    1.342649 
304         1.42786     1.333437
304.5       1.414042    1.324225 
305         1.407133    1.31271
```

My expected output is: 
x1 which is a vector of the amplitude at 412nm and the slope S
I would like to post the figure that i got for the curve fit but I dont know how to do it.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected output, please

Comment: I have now added a part of the data and the expected outputs. Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Will you always have the same number of spectra? Or do you want your code to adapt to this number?

Comment: Hi Billbokeey, No i will have different number of spectra in every spreadsheet and this is another big problem for me as I dont know how to handle this either. Thanks!